# Rabbitmq refuses connection when I set default port

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue

I implement it in java and want to have a constructor for an end point:

```
public EndPoint(final String endPointName, final String host, final int port){
    this.name=endPointName;
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

    factory.setHost(host);
    factory.setPort(port);
    connection = factory.newConnection();

    channel = connection.createChannel();
    channel.queueDeclare(name, false, false, false, null);  

}
```

And I receive `EOFException:connection refused` even when I set the arguments `"localhost"` and `15672` which are considered to be default as far as I understand. The problem is with the method `setPort()`: without it everything works perfectly.

Why do I think that 15672 port is correct? Without `setPort()` I can open my browser Rabbitmq helper at `localhost:15672` and see my created queues.

How can I set the port without an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default port of RabbitMQ's operational protocol is 5672; port 15672 is the default port for the management plugin (the "GUI").

Answer (score 0):

Different releases of RabbitMQ have different default ports. If the code works without the `setPort()` call, then I expect that the default the RabbitMQ  client runtime library uses -- whatever that is -- is correct, and your specific choice of 15672 is not correct.

"connection refused" nearly always means that nothing is actually listening on the specified port.

Comment: when I don't use setPort() I can open in browser localhost:15672 and see my rabbitmq queues created

Comment: try 5672 not 15672

Comment: I don't use RabbitMQ much, so perhaps this is way off, but: could 15672 be an administrative port of some kind, rather than a broker port? As the previous poster noted, 5672 is the usual default for AMQP messaging these days. When I do AMQP with ActiveMQ/Artemis, I can't connect a web browser to the AMQP port.